# Android Jetpack Compose and Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Let's say we have the following code:

```
NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = FRAGMENT_ONE
    ) {
        composable(FRAGMENT_ONE) {
            FragmentOneScreen()
        }
        composable(FRAGMENT_TWO) {
            FragmentTwoScreen()
        }
        composable(FRAGMENT_THREE) {
            FragmentThreeScreen()
        }
    }
```

FragmentOneScreen, FragmentTwoScreen, and FragmentThreeScreen are methods annotated with @composable, and *NavHost* code is placed in MainActivity's onCreate method.

My questions are:

- are FragmentOneScreen, two, and three **fragments**?
- if the answer to the previous question is YES, is this the right way to implement navigation between fragments (no need to create three classes that extend androidx.fragment class, etc and in their onCreateView method to return ComposeView)

I need some help with this because I am having a hard time grasping these questions.

Comment: No, those are Composable views. There's no `Fragments` in Compose unless you create them by yourself.

Comment: As mentioned by others, they are composables.

I just added a very simple app for another question, but it might make sense because of the simplicity :-) 

Project: https://github.com/msuhl/ComposeNavigation

Answer (score 0):

They are composables.

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = SCREEN_ONE) {
    composable(SCREEN_ONE) {
        ScreenOne()
    }
    composable(SCREENT_TWO) {
        ScreenTwo()
    }
    composable(SCREEN_THREE) {
        ScreenThree()
    }
}
```

Rename `fragment` to screen or some other terms to avoid confusion.

Navigation can be done like this,

```
navController.navigate("friends")
```

[Refer Docs for more detailed explaination](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#create-navhost)